# What is wrong with my wp query, cant exclude the category that i want

Tags: query

query('showposts='.$display_count.'&orderby=comment_count&category__not_in=14');

It wont exclude the category that i want. Posts still show up

Answer (score 2):

As far as I remember `category__not_in` takes array of IDs, which are pain to use when written as string.

For single category it would is easier to write it as `cat=-14` (minus before ID).

See [Category Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Category_Parameters) in Codex.

PS I think you meant `query_posts()`, not `query()`?..

Answer (score 0):

example:

```
global $wp_query;           
$wp_query->set('cat', '-14,-1172,-867');
$posts = $wp_query->get_posts();
```